# Java multithreading with EJB Timer Service

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I need to pick a batch of messages (around 20 messages) every minute from database and need to process them concurrently. I am using EJB timer service (Scheduler) for fetching messages from database for every minute.

Basically I need to pick 20-30 messages every minute and after processing these I need to send some mails. There are few database operations involved in processing the messages.

Can you please suggest how I can use executor service framework from java.concurrent package and how these messages will get submitted every minute?

Comment: There are many tutorials to help with the ExecutorService. There are other considerations with the approach:  1) What happens if processing the 20-30 messages takes longer than a minute? 2) What happens if 20-30 messages becomes 50-100?  3) Is each message a transaction (when is db commit)?  4) Does the order of processing the messages matter? 5) Would a pub/sub architecture be more appropriate?

Comment: Hi Andrew, PFB response.1) Yes. It may take more than minute to process all these messages.I need to pick next 20-30 messages  every minute and process them)2)Currently we need to handle 20-30 messages. In case if batch size increase can we park these many messages in some queue??3) No we are committing all the database operations in single transactions  4) No.The order for processing does not matter as each message can be processed independently

Comment: @SanketMurugkar did my answer help you? :) If not could you point out what didn't work?

Comment: @Sneh, Yes it solved my problem. I have done some minor changes based on the business logic.

Comment: Great. Also if you are using countdownlatch, make sure that u countdown it in finally block so that if your message processing throws exception, it doesn't deadlock your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi here is a basic example using Java's ExecutorService, CountDownLatch and CompletableFuture. This example is just to point you out in the right direction and by no means the perfect one and it uses a lot of Java8 stuff (I assumed you are using Java8). Also I am not using EJB Timer stuff, rather going with ScheduledExecutorService but you can easily swap them I guess.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BatchMessageProcessingExample {

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 20;

    //Having 20 here may not entirely benefit you. Chosing this number depends on a lot of stuff.
    // Its usually better to go with total number of cores you have
    private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(BATCH_SIZE);

    private final ScheduledExecutorService databasePool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void schedule() {
        databasePool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> runBatchProcess(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); //Schedule the database work to execute every minute
    }

    private void runBatchProcess() {
        List<Message> taskFromDbFetch = getMessagesFromDb(); //Get stuff from the db
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(taskFromDbFetch.size()); //Create a latch having same size as the list

        List<Task> taskList = taskFromDbFetch.stream().map(x -> new Task(countDownLatch, x)).collect(Collectors.toList()); // Create tasks using the messages and the countdown latch

        taskList.forEach(pool::execute); //Submit them all in pool

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sendEmailAfterCompletion(countDownLatch)); //Send an email out from a separate thread
    }

    private void sendEmailAfterCompletion(CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();//Await on the latch for the batch tasks to complete
            sendEmail();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendEmail() {
        System.out.println("Sending out an email.");
    }

    private List<Message> getMessagesFromDb() { //Get your messages from db here
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < BATCH_SIZE; i++) {
            final int taskNumber = i;
            messages.add(() -> System.out.println("I am a db message number " + taskNumber));
        }

        return messages;
    }

    class Task implements Runnable {

        private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

        private final Message message;

        public Task(CountDownLatch countDownLatch, Message message) {
            this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            message.process(); //Process the message
            countDownLatch.countDown(); //Countdown the latch
        }
    }

    interface Message {
        void process();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BatchMessageProcessingExample().schedule();
    }

}
```